Equivalent function of getargspec in python 3.11
Earlier the Python code was working fine, now they have upgraded to Python 3.11.
We are getting the below error message..
AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'. Did you mean: 'getargs'?

Is there any Equivalent function of getargspec in python 3.11..
Can someone reply please...
Thanks,

There are two possible replacements depending on your needs.
For simple cases you can use inspect.signature which will give you a Signature object. This can be used to read the call signature of a function and its return type annotation. This is the preferred route for any new code.
The inspect.signature documentation can be found here, and the object documentation here.
Another possibility is to use the inspect.getfullargspec function which works similar to the now deprecated inspect.getargspec, you can find the documentation for it here. This function primarily exists to make it easier to update older code that was using the deprecated API.
I hope this helps.
